# Q-IN-Q Tunnel between cisco and mikrotik not work

Tags: cisco, tunnel, dot1q

i have try to make A Q-IN-Q tennel between two router (cisco and Microik) through cisco switch

**in mikrotik**

VLAN ID = 10 IN interface ether1
VLAN ID = 20 in interaface Vlan10
ip address in interface van 20 [ 10.10.10.2/30]

Microtik[ether1] ===>[Ether2]CISCO-SW-nexus[ether1]<<====[Ether1]cisco-router

**in cisco-switch**

ether2 [with microtik] is mode trunk 
ether1 [With router cisco] is Mode Dot1q tunnel

```
switchport mode dot1q-tunnel
switchport access vlan 10
spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
```

in router-cisco

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 no snmp trap link-status
end

enter preformatted text here


switch# sh spanning-tree vlan 10

VLAN0010
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32778
             Address     5000.0001.0007
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32778  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 10)
             Address     5000.0001.0007
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Eth1/1           Desg FWD 4         128.1    P2p
Eth1/2           Desg FWD 4         128.2    P2p
```

the problem is not ping PTP between router cisco and mikrotik with subvlan 20

Comment: We need to see the entire configuration of both devices.   Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: hello , above in a config from my router , is too clear

Comment: I don't see QinQ anywhere, that's just simple 802.1Q tagging.

Comment: hello 
switchport mode dot1q-tunnel
switchport access vlan 10
spanning-tree bpdufilter enable

Comment: bro , in cisco switch i make mode dot1q tunnel at interface going to rotuer , 
and the vlan i trank it to microtik , and in microtik i remove first tag ,

Comment: what Cisco hardware / OS is in use?

Comment: Router cisco csr1000

Comment: With switch nexus